# XML simple parsing

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, sax

I have a question about parsing (Android Studio). It is not about something in particular. My code just doesn't run. No errors. I want to be able to press a button and show a specific text, parsed from an XML file.

For now, i'll omit the button part and throw you the codes just for printing this text on a humble textview

XML CODE (app/src/main/assets follder.  articles.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE articles[
<!ELEMENT articles ANY>
<!ELEMENT article ANY>
<!ATTLIST article ID ID #IMPLIED> ]>
<articles>
 <article ID="a1">TEST
</article>
 <article ID="a2">1.TEST2
</article>
```

CLASS CODE

```
package com.blah.blah;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
String stringArticle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

     try {

         // Loads your XML file as an InputStream
         inputStream = assetManager.open("articles");

         DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);

         Element article = doc.getElementById("a1");
         String stringArticle = article.getTextContent();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(stringArticle);

     } catch (IOException e) {
         // Exception Handling Code
         e.printStackTrace();
     }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (SAXException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
}
```

I haven't tried the techniques that return you a Nodelist, because I dont want to iterate over anything. I find it useless for my project. What I want is something extremely primitive. It's like those simple bible apps. You press the button with the verse and the corresponding text pops up. That simple.

And again, no errors at all! Just not working. I think the TRY part is not executed. Because it gives me the default 'hello world' text on the TextView. But, once i put the

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(stringarticle);
```

lines after the TRY/CATCH blocks, I just get an empty TextView.

TY!

Comment: Did you read the javadoc of [`getElementById()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById-java.lang.String-)? *Note: Attributes with the name "ID" or "id" are not of type ID unless so defined.* Since you don't have a DTD, there are no "type ID" attributes in your XML, so `getElementById()` returns null, causing a `NullPointerException` in the next line, proving that you statement "No errors" is entirely false. You are getting errors, so maybe your should look again.

Comment: I have read, yes. And it made me think about it. But I didn't pay attention because It is my first time with XML and I am pretty sure I don't get any errors...

I changed my XML into this now:



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE articles[
    <!ELEMENT articles ANY>
    <!ELEMENT article ANY>
    <!ATTLIST article type ID #IMPLIED>
]>
<articles>
    <article ID="1">blah</article>
    <article ID="2">asdf</article>
</articles>

Now I get errors: "Attribute ID is not allowed here"

Comment: I have updated my XML code. I think there should no be any problem with it anymore. Thank you very much. Still I get no result. Is there something I need to declare on the manifest.XML ? Like Schema stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your XML file in "app/src/main/assets" directory. After that you can easily access your XML file via "AssetManager" class.

You can use below code as a reference:-

```
 AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        // Loads your XML file as an InputStream
        inputStream = assetManager.open("articles.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        Element article = doc.getElementById("1");
        String stringarticle = article.getTextContent();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(stringarticle);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Exception Handling Code
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Just Remember to place your file in mentioned directory, otherwise "AssetManager" class won't be able to read it.

Cheers !!

Comment: Time for work then! Let's see how this goes! TY very much for help!!

Comment: I get <br/><br/>
FATAL EXCEPTION: main <br/>                                                                                    Process: com.blah.blah, PID: 10748<br/><br/>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity <br/>ComponentInfo{com.greeklawapps.poinikoskodikasdom/com.greeklawapps.poinikoskodikasdom.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String org.w3c.dom.Element.getTextContent()' on a null object reference

Comment: Pointing on my  String stringArticle = article.getTextContent();

Comment: It seems that your "getTextContent()" method is throwing "NullPointerException". Try putting it in try-catch block and see where it goes wrong. Double check your XML file as I have implemented my code using your XML file.

Comment: You have already change your getElementByID method argument.  Check whether that "ID" exists in your XML file

Comment: Yes. Yours is "1". I changed to mine ("a1"). You re right about the .xml. There must be an error there. maybe the path. As soon as i remove the .xml from inputStream = assetManager.open("articles");  goes back to playing and not showing anything like in the beginning. When there is an .XML extension there, i get the error again.

Comment: In the beginning, you were not getting any error because the error producing line retains in Try-Catch Block. It was giving error in the beginning also but your app wasn't crashing. It will be better if you put all your code in Try-Catch block and see the exception and its cause.

Comment: And the TRY does not seem to run anyway. I changed to textView.setText("hii"); for example and I still get the default hello world.

Comment: And content of your XML also

Comment: here you are! I've updated everything to the 'rightnow' condition!

Comment: If error occurs in your try block i.e. first line (in your case) then rest of the lines in try block won't run. It will straight jump to catch block.

Comment: Your first line is giving "FileNotFoundException" (clearly) that's why rest of the lines are not executing. Change it back to "articles.xml" then remove "<!DOCTYPE articles[
    <!ELEMENT articles ANY>
    <!ELEMENT article ANY>
    <!ATTLIST article ID ID #IMPLIED> ]>" from your XML file (just for checking)

Comment: Gives a crash again as soon as i place the .XML  . With or without the attributes declaration on the XML :(

Comment: Got your error !! you was writing "id" tag as "ID" (in capitals) which is an XML syntax error.  Change it to "id" and your null reference error will resolve. Change your XML content to "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE articles[
    <!ELEMENT articles ANY>
    <!ELEMENT article ANY>
    <!ATTLIST article ID ID #IMPLIED> ]>
<articles>
    <article id="a1">TEST
    </article>
    <article id="a2">1.TEST2
    </article>
</articles>"   And don't forget to write your file name as "articles.xml".

Comment: And in your above question edit your XML doesn't contain "</articles>" closing tag.. correct it !!

Comment: IT WORKED!! But why!!! :) I changed to all capitals to be sure. As soon as i change back to normal case, i get the 'Attribute id is not allowed here'!!! But the code runs! I dont get it...

Comment: TY VERY MUCH! Now I must find a way to return the corresponding article based on the View view pressed on a button.